# Python Web Scrape Unknown Number of Pages

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have working code that scrapes a single Craigslist page for specific information, but what would I need to add in order to grab the data from ALL of the pages (not knowing how many pages ahead of time)?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url="https://portland.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=electronics&sort=date"
uClient=uReq(my_url) #sends GET request to URL 
page_html=uClient.read() #reads returned data and puts it in a variable
uClient.close() #close the connection

#create a file that we will want later to write parsed data to
filename="ScrapedData.csv"
f=open(filename, 'w')
headers="date, location, title, price\n"
f.write(headers)

#use BS to parse the webpage
page_soup=soup(page_html,'html.parser') #applying BS to the obtained html
containers=page_soup.findAll('p',{'class','result-info'})

for container in containers:
    container_date=container.findAll('time',{'class','result-date'})  
    date=container_date[0].text
    try:
        container_location=container.findAll('span',{'class','result-hood'})
        location=container_location[0].text
    except:
        try:
            container_location=container.findAll('span',{'class','nearby'})
            location=container_location[0].text
        except:
            location='NULL'
    container_title=container.findAll('a',{'class','result-title'})
    title=container_title[0].text
    try:
        container_price=container.findAll('span',{'class','result-price'})
        price=container_price[0].text
    except:
        price='NULL'

    #to print to screen
    print('date:'+date)
    print('location:'+location)
    print('title:'+title)
    print('price:'+price)
    #to write to csv
    f.write(date+','+location.replace(",","-")+','+title.replace(","," ")+','+price+'\n')

f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from what sir Andersson has already shown, you can do that as well for this site:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

page_link = "https://portland.craigslist.org/search/sss?s={}&query=electronics&sort=date"
for link in [page_link.format(page) for page in range(0,1147,120)]: #this is the fix
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    for container in soup.select('.result-info'):
        try:
            date = container.select('.result-date')[0].text
        except IndexError:
            date = ""
        try:
            title = container.select('.result-title')[0].text
        except IndexError:
            title = ""
        try:
            price = container.select('.result-price')[0].text
        except IndexError:
            price = ""

        print(date,title,price)
        with open("craigs_item.csv","a",newline="",encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            writer.writerow([date,title,price])
```

Comment: This works! But is there any way to modify it without knowing the number of pages? That's the main thing

Comment: There is no page number mentioned in the url; rather, it is the quantity of data that you can see.

Comment: Right, so is there a way to loop through until there are no more items?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to loop through all pages by handling `"s"` parameter in URL until you find page with no results (page with text `"search and you will find"`):

```
import requests

results_counter = 0
while True:
    my_url="https://portland.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=electronics&sort=date&s=%d" % results_counter
    page_html = requests.get(my_url).text
    if "search and you will find" in page_html:
        break
    else:
        results_counter += 120

        filename="ScrapedData.csv"
        f=open(filename, 'w')
        headers="date, location, title, price\n"
        f.write(headers)

        page_soup=soup(page_html,'html.parser') #applying BS to the obtained html
        containers=page_soup.findAll('p',{'class','result-info'})
        ...
```

Comment: So I added the rest of my code from 'from container..' and it doesn't error out, but the .csv file is empty?

Comment: Does your prints works as expected? Can you see required data?

Comment: No. But maybe I didn't combine it with my code correctly? I just added everything after yours, but not nested inside. I tried nesting but I got errors. It might have something to do with the url not having the page number at the end like you specified?

Comment: There are no page numbers in URL, but results number displayed on page, e.g. `s=0` (0-120), `s=120` (120-240), `s=240`(240-360), etc

Comment: Do I need to move the 's=%d' to where it shows up in the url though? because it isn't at the end of the url

Comment: No. It doesn't depends on place in URL